# Direct tab open

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

On a `page-1.php`, I have multiple tabs in which, one of them is called `"Points"`.

```
<div class="tabs">
   <a href="#setting"> setting</a> 
   <a href="#points"> Points</a>
</div>
<div class="active" id="setting"> Show setting</div> 
<div id="points"> Show points</div>
```

By default, the `Setting` tab is shown.

On a different page, `page-2.php`, I have a button:

```
  <button> 
       <a href="http://example.com/page-1/#points">Go to Point tab</a>        
  </button>
```

So, I amt trying to make it so that when the `Go to point tab` button is clicked, I want the `Point` tab to be opened.

How can I achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: This is nothing to do with PHP, this is JavaScript, have submitted tag changes

Comment: Thank you. I closed the question. Thank you for the link,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your link has to be `page-1.php#points` (unless you're using mod-rewrite to rewrite your URL's). If that alone isn't working, you need to use either JavaScript or CSS to make the selected tab active.

You can use CSS to manage which tab is active and displayed. See [this article on using the :target selector](https://css-tricks.com/better-linkable-tabs/).

Or you can use JavaScript to fetch the current hash from the URL, set that tab content as visible, and hide all the other tabs.